# Missing object reference in Outlook add-in (VB)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, office-addins

First of all, I am not a professional developer, I code only for fun so there are many, many things I don't know.

I created an Outlook add-in in VS Community 2019 in VB that is working fine. In that add-in, I manipulate a text string variable.

I need to update the add-in so that this text string variable is Base64 encoded.

Below is the overall simple structure of the add-in and the code that I added to Base64 encode the variable "SearchTerm"

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown
    End Sub

    Public Sub SearchText()

        Dim SearchTerm As String
        Dim data As Byte()
        Dim EncodedSearchTerm

        SearchTerm = "Text to encode"
        data = UTF8Encoding.GetBytes(SearchTerm)
        EncodedSearchTerm = Convert.ToBase64String(data)

    End Sub

End Class
```

I get an error on the line `data = UTF8Encoding.GetBytes(SearchTerm)` that says

> Class System.Text.UTF8Encoding
> BC30469: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

I have seen that UTF8Encoding.GetBytes() belongs to System.Text Namespace. It seems that this is already referenced in my solution. I guess I need to add/create an object reference in the code (but I'm not sure what that really means), or my code is completely wrong!

I would appreciate help!

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write `data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SearchTerm)`.

Comment: Or  `... Convert.ToBase64String(New UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("Text to encode"))` -- `UTF8Encoding` is a class and `GetBytes()` is not static (`Shared`), so you need an instance of that class to call one of its instance method. `Encoding.UTF8` is instead a static property.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you. Both solutions work indeed.

Thanks Jimi for the explanations, I think I understood :-)